# Traefik different entrypoint and rule combos

Tags: traefik

I have a docker compose file, I want to host my container on `example.com:8080` and `api.example.com:443`, I can accomplish that goal right now.

However I don't want 2 seperate service for that, I want to eliminate either `my_api` or `abcxyz` and have 1 service only and accomplish the same behavior, i.e. my container should be hosted at `example.com:8080` and not on `example.com:443` AND `api.example.com:443` but not on `api.example.com:8080`

Is there a way to do it under 1 service.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=false
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=web-secure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.spiderman.address=:8080
      - --providers.file.directory=/configuration/
      - --providers.file.watch=true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./certificates.yml:/configuration/certificates.yml:ro
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  my_api:
    image: traefik/whoami
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.entrypoints=spiderman"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.tls=true"
  abcxyz:
    image: traefik/whoami
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.abcxyz.entrypoints=web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.abcxyz.rule=Host(`api.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.abcxyz.tls=true"
```

I could do -

```yaml
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.entrypoints=spiderman,web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.rule=Host(`example.com`,`api.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.my_api.tls=true"
```

but it would also serve at `example.com:443` which I don't want because i want to host my cool wordpress site there! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=false
      - --api.insecure=false
      - --providers.docker
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=web-secure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true
      - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.spiderman.address=:8080
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.3:80:80
      - 127.0.0.3:443:443
      - 127.0.0.3:8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock
  my_api:
    image: traefik/whoami
    hostname: my_api
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      - traefik.http.routers.example_com.entrypoints=spiderman
      - traefik.http.routers.example_com.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.example_com.service=my_api
      - traefik.http.routers.example_com.tls=true

      - traefik.http.routers.my_api.entrypoints=web-secure
      - traefik.http.routers.my_api.rule=Host(`api.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.my_api.tls=true
      - traefik.http.services.my_api.loadBalancer.server.port=80
```

Note that here I've bound everything to local address `127.0.0.3` for testing, but of course that's not necessary; I did that to avoid conflicts with existing services I have listening on ports 80, 443, and 8080.

### Testing

I've defined this shell function that ensures the various hostname:port combinations resolve correctly (you could edit `/etc/hosts` instead to accomplish the same thing) and shows the HTTP status code for each request:

```
fetch() {
  curl -sf \
    --resolve api.example.com:443:127.0.0.3 \
    --resolve api.example.com:8080:127.0.0.3 \
    --resolve example.com:443:127.0.0.3 \
    --resolve example.com:8080:127.0.0.3 \
    -k -w '%{stderr}%{http_code}\n' $1
}
```

Using that, let's test our your various requirements.

> my container should be hosted at example.com:8080

```
$ fetch https://example.com:8080 | grep -i host
200
Hostname: my_api
Host: example.com:8080
X-Forwarded-Host: example.com:8081
```

> and not on example.com:443

```
$ fetch https://example.com:443 | grep -i host
404
```

> AND api.example.com:443

```
$ fetch https://api.example.com:443 | grep -i host
200
Hostname: my_api
Host: api.example.com
X-Forwarded-Host: api.example.com
```

> but not on api.example.com:8080

```
$ fetch https://api.example.com:8080 | grep -i host
404
```

I think that covers your requirements!